# Debugging Javascript in VSCode on Mac

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

I use VSCode for my main editor, but when I debug plain native javascript I have always done it in the browser.  Reason? Because I can't get the debugger to work.

Is this possible with native javascript?

I have tried the chrome debugger extension, but that always times out.

I simply have a single line of code in my javascript file

`document.write("Hello World!");`

I would really like to use the debugger in vscode, but I am not having much luck.

Node version is set to v8.1.2

This is my launch.json config:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}]/*.js"]
    }
]
}
```

What else do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do the same on Ubuntu and it should work on Mac too, using following configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html",
            "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Obviously my `html` file is named `index.html` and resides in workspace root.